# static struct array prints garbage after loading lua file

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, lua

I have a static struct array of which is filled by data parsed from a lua file.

I thought I was doing every right, but as soon as I went to load another lua file, the static array started printing garbage. I'm not exactly sure what's going on behind the scenes with loading the lua file, but I haven't been able to reproduce it any other way.

Here is a my code and the lua file I am loading.

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILES 5
#define MAX_BOXES 25

struct Box
{
  const char *name;
  int count;
  const char *files[MAX_FILES];
};

static struct Box boxes[MAX_BOXES];
static int box_index = 0;

void script_bail (lua_State * S, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list argp;
  va_start(argp, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, argp);
  va_end(argp);
  lua_close(S);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int box_create (const char* name, int count, const char **files)
{
  if (box_index + 1 >= MAX_BOXES)
    return 1;

  boxes[box_index].name = name;
  boxes[box_index].count = count;
  memcpy(boxes[box_index].files, files, count * sizeof(char*));

  box_index++;

  return 0;
}

void load_boxes (lua_State* S)
{
  const char * name;
  const char * files[MAX_FILES];

  int element_index = 1;
  int file_index = 0;

  lua_getglobal(S, "boxes");

  if (!lua_istable(S, -1))
    script_bail (S, "'%s' is not a table\n", "boxes");

  /* each element has no key */
  lua_pushnil(S);

  /* iterate through this table of tables */
  while (lua_next(S, -2)) {

    if (!lua_istable(S, -1))
      script_bail (S,
          "Element %d of table `classes' is not a table!\n",
          element_index);

    /* find variable by name `name' and make sure it's a string */
    lua_pushstring(S, "name");
    lua_gettable(S, -2);

    if (!lua_isstring(S, -1))
      script_bail (S, "invalid field in table for key: %s", "name");

    name = lua_tostring(S, -1);

    lua_pop(S, 1);

    /* get the table where that's named `components' */
    lua_pushstring(S, "files");
    lua_gettable(S, -2);

    if (!lua_istable(S, -1))
      script_bail (S,
          "files of element %d is not a table!\n",
          element_index);

    /* each component has no key */
    lua_pushnil(S);

    /* go through each component */
    while (lua_next(S, -2)) {

      if (!lua_isstring(S, -1))
        script_bail (S,
            "Element %d of files of box %d is not a string!\n",
            file_index, element_index);

      /* add the component file to our index and increment the index */
      files[file_index++] = lua_tostring(S, -1);

      /* pop current to move to next */
      lua_pop(S, 1);
    }

    if (box_create(name, file_index, files) != 0)
      script_bail(S, "boxes exceeds limit of %d\n", MAX_BOXES);

    /* pop the files table */
    /* pop the current table to make room for the next */
    lua_pop(S, 2);

    element_index++;
    file_index = 0;
  }

  lua_pop(S, 1);
}

lua_State * load_lua_file (const char *filename)
{
  lua_State * S = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(S);

  if (luaL_loadfile(S, filename) || lua_pcall(S, 0, 0, 0))
    script_bail (S, "Can't load %s into memory\n", filename);

  return S;
}

void print_boxes()
{
  struct Box *box;

  printf("index: %d\n", box_index);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < box_index; i++) {
    box = &boxes[i];

    printf("%p: %s => {", box, box->name);

    for (j = 0; j < box->count; j++) {
      printf(" %s ", box->files[j]);
    }

    printf("}\n");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  lua_State * S = load_lua_file ("boxes.lua");
  load_boxes(S);
  lua_close(S);

  print_boxes();

  lua_State * N = load_lua_file ("boxes.lua");
  lua_close(N);

  print_boxes();

  return 0;
}
```

```
boxes = { 
  { name = "first", files = { "one.lua" } },
  { name = "second", files = { "two.lua", "three.lua", "four.lua" } }
};
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
0x10f985330: first => { one.lu }
0x10f985368: second => { two.lu  three.lua  four.lua }

0x10f985330: second => { D }
0x10f985368: D => { J?????  ?
                        (?   }
```

I want to note that this works sporadically. Sometimes it prints the same data twice (hinting that it is working). Most of the time I get the above. What am I doing wrong that causes memory for the array to become corrupted?

Comment: Don't use global variables, your code is hard to understand because of that.

Comment: Try wrapping `lua_tostring()` with `strdup(lua_tostring())`, is the problem gone?

Comment: @iharob that seems to fix the issue. can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: Don't do that move `lua_close(S)` to the end of `main()` and it should work as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you make a pointer to a block of memory that is deallocated at some point, I think here

```
lua_close(S);
```

Then when you try to access `files` or `name` in the structures the pointers point to garbage.

You need to copy the strings, you can use `strdup()` or any equivalent function for that, every string for which you save a pointer, must still be valid when you print the boxes.

A better solution would be not to deallocate the memory allocated by the lua library before printing the boxes, you can do that by moving the `lua_close(S);` after the `print_boxes()` call.

Because if you use `strdup()` then you must call `free()` on the pointers after you don't need to access them anymore, that would not work directly because the poitners are qualified with `const`, so if you use `strdup()` you need to

1. Remove `const` from the struct members definition.
2. Call `free()` on every pointer that points to a value returned by `strdup()`.